# Nginx proxy_pass rule for accessing my dockerized flask app

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn, plotly-dash

I'm new in using nginx as proxy.

I'm looking for a dynamic mode to rewrite my locations inside the nginx conf file in order to avoid multiple entries, as below:

```
location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://app1:8000;
}

location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://app2:8000;
}

location /app3 {
    proxy_pass http://app3:8000;
}

location /appn {
    proxy_pass http://appn:8000;
}
```

Each time the user ask for location "/appx" the docker container named "appx" and running relative flask app served by gunicorn must be returned.
The solution reported in code above works, but I need to use just one location and some rewriting rules.
I've tried also the following rule without success:

```
location ~ ^/app/(?<appname>\w+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://$appname:8000;
}
```

My location should start with "/app".

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass http://$appname:8000$request_uri;`